# Creating x objects using array and map

Tags: javascript, for-loop

I want to create 10 `Fly` objects in a functional manner. I thought this would work:

```
var flies = new Array(10).map(function() {
    return new Fly();
});
```

It doesn't. It creates an array of length ten with `undefined` as their values.

How can I create 10 objects without using `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)...`?

EDIT: This is an **academic exercise** for the sake of learning only. It's find if a `for` is used under the hood. I'm just trying to figure out what JavaScript can do.

Comment: `Array.apply(0, Array(10)).map`

Comment: `for(var i = 0; i < 10; i++)` seems like the best way to solve this problem.  Why do you not want to use it?

Comment: May you enlighten us on why wouldn't you use `for` ?

Comment: `[0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9].map` - if you're dead set against `for`

Comment: Read the docs for [array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map): `callback is invoked only for indexes of the array which have assigned values; it is not invoked for indexes that are undefined, those which have been deleted or which have never been assigned values.`

Comment: In ES6 you'll be able to do: `Array.from({length: 10}, _ => new Fly());`

Comment: If it's a personal thing against `for`, you can use: `var i=0; while(i<10){ /*...*/; i++ }` - =P

Comment: This is a particularly wasteful approach, but it's at least interesting at the academic level: `new Array(10).join().split(',').map(function() { return new Fly(); });`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Out of the box, there is only @elcanrs way.
If you use a library such as Underscore you could use http://underscorejs.org/#times

```
var flies = _.times(10, function(){return new Fly()})
```

Comment: Guess what `_.times` uses to do this?  Yep!  A *for*: `for (var i = 0; i < n; i++) accum[i] = iteratee(i);` :-D

Comment: Actually they use Array for creating an accumulator and then _.iteratee which uses more calls that a for() for sure http://underscorejs.org/docs/underscore.html

Comment: I was just pointing out that the OPs restriction to not use `for` is silly since any other solution will probably just use it internally.

Comment: Indeed, in JavaScript the best way may be a for not a _.times.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: once we get TCO we won't need to use loops anymore! yay

Comment: What is TCO? Tail-call optimization?

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty sure that any *fancy* approach will be using a `for`, or another loop, at a lower level... If you reeeealy want to get rid of this, you can work with a recursive approach and create your own Fly Factory function!

**Honestly, IMO it's a waste of effort. But at least it has not for loop! =D**

```js
function Fly() {
}

function CreateFlies(n) {
    var arr = [new Fly()];
    arr = (n > 1 ? arr.concat(CreateFlies(n-1)) : arr);
    return arr;
}
var flies = CreateFlies(10);
alert(flies);
```